# Django produce sql with table name different then specified in meta db_table

Tags: django, oracle, django-models, cx-oracle

I'm using django 1.4 with oracle backend

In my models.py I have:

```
 class ProteinTherapeutics(models.Model):
#...
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'mnowotka\".\"protein_therapeutics'
        managed=False
```

And this:

```
ProteinTherapeutics.objects.exists()
```

produces this SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT ROWNUM AS "_RN",
          "_SUB".*
   FROM
     (SELECT (1) AS "A"
      FROM "MNOWOTKA"."PROTEIN_THERAPEFB7C") "_SUB"
   WHERE ROWNUM <= 1)
WHERE "_RN" > 0  [1.99ms]
```

Can you help me, please?

Answer (score -1):

I guess the problem is in table name length. I don't know django, but I think it tries to shorten the name **mnowotka"."protein_therapeutics** (31 characters) to 30 chars. Maybe there is some meta for schema like

```
class ProteinTherapeutics(models.Model):
#...
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'protein_therapeutics'
        schema = 'mnowotka'
        managed=False
```